# HQL query for Collection using ON clause

Tags: java, join, collections, hql, on-clause

Below is the HQL query which gives me the syntax error when I use join Operation with ON clause on the Collection property.

I have a Source.java file with one Collection property of the Customer bean with OneToMany mapping which is mapped by source property in Customer bean.

HQL Query :

```
select s.name from Source s 
join Customer c on s.customer.id = c.id
```

Java class snippet:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "source")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Customer> customer = new HashSet<>();
    
   I have Customer.java which has ManyToOne relation with Source bean  
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="source_id")
    private Source source;
```

Comment: I don't see any HQL query

Comment: HQL Query :

select s.name from Source s 
join Customer c on s.customer.id = c.id

Comment: Try something like: `select s.name from Source s join s.customer c`

Comment: It is working but I want to use ON clause

Comment: Alright, how about: `select s.name from Source s join Customer c on c.source=s` (s.customer is not a customer: it's a set)

Comment: I tried 
select s.name from Source s 
join Customer c on s.customer.id = c
Gave me 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile

Comment: customer property in your Source class is a collection, so you can't use a JOIN with ON because you must take the indexed element to put in relation. But which is your aim? Because you can write your query in several ways